# How to generate all possible k size vectors in a matrix (diagonals included)?

Tags: python, matrix, permutation

Given this matrix:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]
```

What is an efficient way to return all the possible 4 by 1 vectors and 1 by 4 matrix in this matrix. As well as any 4 diagonal spaces joined in a line.

For example:
`[1,1,1,1]` would appear 3 times

Diagonals also need to be addressed so `[1,2,3,4]` would be included as a row but also a diagonal.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to approach the problem. So have basically gotten nowhere.

Comment: if you're stuck on a problem, solve a simpler one or a subcase and build up to the main problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the problem into two steps:

**Step 1 - get all horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines**

Diagonals are tackled using the fact either `i+j`, or respectively `i-j`, is constant for the indexes `i, j`

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]

pprint.pprint(x)

# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

all_lines = (
    # Horizontal
    [x[i] for i in range(len(x))] +
    # Vertical
    [[x[i][j] for i in range(len(x))] for j in range(len(x[0]))] +
    # Diagonal k = i - j
    [[x[k+j][j] for j in range(len(x[0])) if 0 <= k+j < len(x)] for k in range(-len(x[0])+1, len(x))] +
    # Diagonal k = i + j
    [[x[k-j][j] for j in range(len(x[0])) if 0 <= k-j < len(x)] for k in range(len(x[0])+len(x)-1)]
)
```

```
>>> pprint.pprint(all_lines)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
 [5],
 [4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2],
 [1],
 [1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [4, 5],
 [5]]
```

**Step 2 - for each line select each 4-length slice**

```
ans = [a[i:i+4] for i in range(len(a)-4+1) for a in all_lines if len(a[i:i+4]) == 4]
```

```
>>> ans = [a[i:i+4] for i in range(len(a)-4+1) for a in all_lines if len(a[i:i+4]) == 4]
>>> pprint.pprint(ans)
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Maybe not be the most efficient but it's at least a way of doing it.
There will likely be a way of using itertools `combinations` to simplify this dramatically.